# JavaScript eval in JavaApplication: "javax.script.scriptException: Expected operand but found"

Tags: javascript, java

In my Java Application, Im relying on JavaScript, implemented via ScriptEngine, to interpret and calculate some basic mathequations I read from a String.

Here is what Ive got:

```
public void calc(String comp){
try {
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine eng = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            res[k] = (Integer) eng.eval(comp);

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in res: " +e);
        }
    }
}
```

No matter which input, excuting will result in:

> Error in res: javax.script.ScriptException: :1:5 Expected an operand but found ,
>   [3, -, 3]
>        ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 5, here with exemplary input comp = "3-3"

.

Or:

> Error in public int[] res: javax.script.ScriptException: :1:6 Expected an operand but found *
>   [-12, *, 3]
>         ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 6

I dont know JavaScript so I dont know what to do in order to fix this error.

Comment: Which javascript String do you pass to the Engine ?

Comment: What are you talking about, as I said, I dont know anything about javaScript

Comment: So what is `comp` ? Fortran code ?

Comment: No its just a mathematical expression, eg. "3+5" or "2*9" or whatever

Comment: It _looks_ like the string is a stringified array, so you'll either need to `join()` the array in JavaScript before you pass it to your Java app, or write some Java code to do so. It would help to see the JS code that is using this Java.

Comment: Try printing value of `comp` which you are passing to `eval`. Something tells me it may not be `3+5` as you claim.

Comment: For example: `var str =  [3, '-', 3].join('');` will give you `"3-3"`

Comment: Ill try that later thanks for your advice. Feel free to post an answer, ill upvote and approve if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the string is a stringified array, so you'll either need to `join()` the array in JavaScript before you pass it to your Java app, or write some Java code to do so.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var str = [3, '-', 3].join(''); // "3-3"
```